# Multiple inputs for 5.1 audio system

Tags: switches, audio, speakers

this is my first post here and I hope I chose the right SE site.
I have a Logitech X-530 5.1 audio system, which is very old and supports input using 3 3.5mm jacks for Front, Rear and Sub (I suppose, green, orange and black jacks).

I'm currently using the system with the provided 3-female-jacks-to-2-female-RCA adapter and a RCA-to-3.5mm-jack cable connected to the computer. I know the system is used as a 2.1 one and it wasn't a big deal, until I decided to update my working station and include additional computers.

Right now, I would like to connect the speakers with 3 computers which will output audio but not at the same time. One computer has an integrated 5.1 sound card, another has a USB 5.1 sound card with an additional Line In jack and the last one just the headphones jack.

Is it possible to achieve this setting by making a switch like [this one](https://www.instructables.com/id/35mm-51-Surround-Sound-Switch-Splitter-Box/)?
How would the circuit be changed in order to have 3 output jacks (for the speakers) and 3x3 input jacks for the computers the switch has to act on?
Are there any electonic-related info I need to worry about? In case I don't have a soldering unit, do you know any already made switches or alternatives?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Well. Of course there is. And even better than the example you mentioned, you could just try and search for a 5P3T switch, which can do everything at once. (or XPYT with X>4, Y>2) But this is a shopping recommendation. Your question is asking for shopping recommendations (not directly, but it does), and might be considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice regarding user interface would be to select the input with the least amount of fumbling with switches. A rotary switch could be an option. Here's an example showing a 6-positions 2-pole switch:

[image]

Turning the knob turns all switches simultaneously so this switch would allow to select one stereo source (2 channels) from 6 sources.

Here you'd need at least 3-position switch since you have 3 audio sources, and 6 poles since you have 6 channels. This will require some searching, but you'll probably find one. Here's a [4 pole 3 positions](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Alpha-Taiwan/SR2511F-0403-19R0B-E9-N-W-159?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvNbjZ2WlReYnXCw5Ewy7NZU1f5KY1%2F5XQ%3D) switch as an example.

Another solution would be with pushbuttons, same as your usual home theatre amplifier. I'd recommend a trip to the nearest electronics junkyard to gut a broken 5.1 amplifier. Failing that, you can pick [6PST or 6PDT pushbutton switches](https://www.mouser.fr/Electromechanical/Switches/Pushbutton-Switches/_/N-5g30?P=1z0z25wZ1z0z267&Ns=Pricing%7C0), latching (not momentary). But if you use independent switches, then when you push one to switch on a source you'll have to switch off the previous one, so that's 2 button presses.

**Edit: schematic with pushbuttons**

[image]

All grounds (sleeves) are connected together.

Each channel has a bus (light green) connected to the corresponding output.

Each input can be connected to its corresponding bus via the pushbuttons (red lines).

If two buttons are pushed at the same time, two inputs will be connected to the same output. This is usually not a problem as most audio devices will tolerate a short. If you are paranoid you can replace the red wires in the drawing with resistors, say 330R.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @peufeu and sorry for the delay. I was investigating your info and I decided to go for 3 6PDT switches, one for every source. However, even though I created many electronic circuits in the past, I'm not familiar with this type of switches. Could you please give me a hint about how to do the wiring? I was reasoning in terms of TRS for every jack but maybe I'm overthinking and can't figure out a way. Could you please look at the following image? https://imgur.com/a/ICURo7i Thank you so much!

Comment: I've drawn a quick'n'dirty schematic over your image. The switch pinout should be in the datasheet, there's no reason to assume all manufacturers agree on a single pinout, that would be way too simple!.....

Comment: That was extremely helpful, thanks! Yeah, finding the pinout is always a nightmare, I will use the multimeter anyway. Since I will put all the circuits in a plastic box, how do I need to handle the ground connection? Is it ok to just wire S pins together or I need some contact on/outside the box?

Comment: I think you'll be OK wiring all S pins together. Keep the wiring tight (large loops pick up magnetic fields).